# How to convert an HTTP request made in Postman to a request in IntelliJ HTTP Client?

Tags: intellij-idea, postman

How would I execute a query in IntelliJ?

I create a `.http` file but how will the parameters in postman respond in this file?
Is it possible somehow maybe to convert such a query from postman to http file right away? Or should it be done manually and how will it look like?

Comment: I don't know of any automated tools to do this. I would write the query manually in IntelliJ.

Comment: The state changed recently

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to convert Postman Collections to IntelliJ IDEA `.http` files using a dedicated JetBrains [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22438-import-from-postman-collections).

1. First, you’ll need to export your collection and environment from Postman as JSON files. See the Postman [documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting/exporting-data/#exporting-collections) for more information on how to do this.
2. Install the **Import from Postman Collections** plugin. You can read more about plugin installation in the IntelliJ IDEA [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html).
3. Click *Try It* in the resulting window. Alternatively, you can find the import action in *Search Everywhere* (Double ⇪Shift) by typing `Import from Postman`.
   In the resulting dialog, select your JSON collection file and click Convert.

After that, the IDE will open a converted `.http` file.

Answer (score 1):

On Enterprise version (not sure about Community) IntellJ has Examples, where you can check how to map the Postman requests to IntellJ version.
I'm not sure if there exists an automatic tool, but it is pretty straightforward mapping.
You can also check the [official IntelliJ HTTP Client docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.3/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2022.3)

[image: Examples button placement]

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to implement this in Java, Postman can generate a Java representation of your request. By default Postman can generate Java code using the `OkHttp` and `Unirest` libraries.

To do this, click the `</>` icon in Postman to open the Code snippet pane.
From the dropdown, choose one of the Java options. Copy that code into your Java project and adapt it as required.

Comment: IntelliJ has a text-based HTTP client that replaces Postman, curl, etc. It is built into the IDE and has its own syntax. This isn't Java code inside the app the OP is writing. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.2/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html for more details if you are interested.